# UIWebview crash with error :EXC_BREAKPOINT (CODE=EXC_I386_BPT, SUBCODE = 0X0)

Tags: swift, uiwebview, xcode8

My program crashes every time the compiler tries to create a webview after getting some data from Json object. It crashed with this error:

> EXC_BREAKPOINT (CODE=EXC_I386_BPT, SUBCODE = 0X0)

Note: any other object (`UIlabel`, `UIButton`, `UItextfield`, etc) is created successfully without the program crashing, only the `UIWEBView` causes the program to crash.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
getdata(){ (boolValue) -> () in
        self.loadimg()
        self.reloadInputViews()
        SwiftLoading().hideLoading()
    }
}

func loadimg()
{
    for L in 0..<Basketpic.count{

        var webv = UIWebView()
        let link = NSURL(string:Basketpic[L])
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: link! as URL) as URLRequest
        webv.loadRequest(requestObj)
        webv.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        webv.frame = CGRect(x: 280 , y:100 + ( 120 * L ), width: 90, height: 100)

        /*let webv = UIWebView()
        let link = NSURL(string:Basketpic[L])
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: link! as URL) as URLRequest
        webv.loadRequest(requestObj)
        webv.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        webv.frame = CGRect(x: 280 , y:100 + ( 120 * L ), width: 90, height: 100)*/

        /*let name = UILabel()
        name.text = (BasketNames[L])
        name.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        name.frame = CGRect(x: 140 , y: 100 + (120 * L), width: 150, height: 100)

        let price = UILabel()
        price.text = (String(BasketPrices[L]))
        price.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        price.frame = CGRect(x: 55 , y: 100 + (120 * L), width: 100, height: 100)*/

        // view.addSubview(name)
        // view.addSubview(price)
        // view.addSubview(webv)
    }

    /* let sum = BasketPrices.reduce(0, +)
    let total = UILabel()
    total.text = (String(sum))
    total.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    let L = BasketPrices.count
    total.frame = CGRect(x: 55 , y: 100 + (120 * L ), width: 100, height: 100)

    let totall = UILabel()
    totall.text = ("المجموع الكلي")
    totall.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    totall.frame = CGRect(x: 155 , y: 100 + (120 * L ), width: 100, height: 100)

    view.addSubview(totall)
    view.addSubview(total) */
}

func getdata(completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool)->())
{
    let listUrlString = "http://burjuman.net/kkkls/basketreview.php"
    let myUrl = URL(string: listUrlString);
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET";

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
            if let result = json["result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for blog in result {
                    if let basket = blog["basket"] as? String {
                        if let id = blog["id"] as? String {
                            if let userid = blog["User_Id"] as? String {
                                if(userid == "75")
                                {
                                    Basketpic.append(basket)
                                    print(userid)
                                    print(id)
                                    print(basket)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        }
        print(Basketpic)
        completion (true)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Try dispatching anything that changes the UI onto the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display UI element after a request, you need to use :

(In Swift3)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    /* What you want to display, update label, show webview */
}
```